# Check if a variable is exactly the same in a line of a file-Tkinter

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter

I've been trying to check if a string from an entry is exactly the same with a possible string in a line of a file.txt that i have created. As i have it right now, the problem is that it doesnt search exactly the string i want,instead if i type "" , it matches because inside the txt there are spaces and if i type for example "qw" it fill find the string qwpero. The login must be successful only when it finds for example the "qepero" string. Here is a part of my code that's important. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def checkconnect():
   password_verify = passwordvar.get()

   with open('file.txt') as f:
       for line in f:
        if password_verify in line:
              global dwm
              global ip_1
              global ip_2
              ip_1 = line.split()[0]
              ip_2 = line.split()[1]
              dwm = line.split()[2]
              loginscreen()
       else:
               global fail_label
               fail_label = tk.Label(frame,text="Λάθος κωδικός-Προσπάθησε ξανά!",bg='#80c1ff')
               fail_label.pack()
```

And the file looks like this :

```
2 3 101 4s3GSs
4 5 102 wqpkdw 
6 7 103 q21kow 
8 9 104 wqmc12  
10 11 105 qwdqwq
```

Comment: If you know your `file.txt` is of that format, why not `split` based on the whitespace? That is, do `example = line.split(' ')`, and you could compare the passed-in string directly. That is, `if 'qw' == example[3]`

Comment: I think this might be the solution,lemme check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line `if password_verify in line:`. 
if password_verify is empty string or whitespace, or any other character in the line, this will be true. Is the password meant to be the last entry in the line? like `4s3GSs`? Then why not check that explicitly?

```py
def checkconnect():
    password_verify = passwordvar.get()

    with open('file.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            my_list = line.split()
            global dwm
            global ip_1
            global ip_2
            ip_1 = my_list[0]
            ip_2 = my_list[1]
            dwm = my_list[2]
            if password_verify == dwm:
                loginscreen()
            else:
                global fail_label
                fail_label = tk.Label(frame, text="Λάθος κωδικός-Προσπάθησε ξανά!", bg='#80c1ff')
                fail_label.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly.

So you are trying to only get EXACT matching lines.
so if the line is "foo" then it should not match "fo"?

if u say:

```py
line = "foo"
print("fo" in line)  # True
print("fo" == line)  # False
print("foo" in line)  # True
print("foo" == line)  # True
```

So the in statement looks if the string exist IN the line.
Wile the == operator checks if both string are exactly the same.

Comment: Exactly.So basically i want == instead of in but then it will check the whole line which of course isn't true. So i need to split all the lines beforehand and say something like 

```
 if password_verify == line[3]

```

Is that somehow possible?